# How do I dynamically add CSS classes to HTML elements if value is less or greater than 0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, class, axios, conditional-statements

How can I dynamically add css classes to the `<div class="coin__row-text">` elements based on whether or not the value of the element is greater than 0?

HTML:

```
<template> 
    <div class="coin-block-wrapper">
        <div class="coin__wrapper">
            <div v-for="(value, key) in coins" :key="value" class="coin__row">
                <div class="coin__row-div">
                    <img src="{{ }}" class="coin__row-logo">
                    <div class="coin-name">{{key}}</div>
                    <div class="coin-name">USDT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="coin__row-div-large">
                    <div id="coin__row-small-div">
                        <div class="coin__row-text">{{value.USD.PRICE}}</div>
                        <div class="coin__row-text">{{value.BTC.PRICE}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="coin__row-small-div">
                        <div class="coin__row-text">{{value.USD.CHANGEPCTHOUR}}%</div>
                        <div class="coin__row-text">{{value.BTC.CHANGEPCTHOUR}}%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Styles:

```
<style scoped>
    .positive {
        color: green;
    }
        
    .negative {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try binding class.
Something like that:

```
<div :class="getDivClasses(value.USD.PRICE)">
```

and inside methods:

```
getDivClasses(value) {
  return value > 0 ? "positive" : "negative";
},
```

Comment: <div :class="value.USD.PRICE > 0 ? 'coin__row-text positive' : 'coin_row-text negative' ">{{value.USD.PRICE}}</div>